# how to change content to display according to radio button that user select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm going to create 3 radio buttons for user to select. Once, user click on that button, it will show user the description of that radio button that user selected.

**For example**

```
- if user select first radio button ==> it will show the description under that
                                        radio button

- if user select second radio button ==> it will show the description under that
                                        radio button

- if user select third radio button ==> it will show the description under that
                                        radio button
```

**My code**

```
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='1' />&nbsp;This is content A of request</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='2' />&nbsp;This is content B of request</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='3' />&nbsp;This is content C of request</p>
<div id='show'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content_type').on('change', function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    switch(n)
    {
            case '1':
                  document.getElementById('#show').innerHTML="1st radio button";
                  break;
            case '2':
                  document.getElementById('#show').innerHTML="2nd radio button";
                  break;
            case '3':
                  document.getElementById('#show').innerHTML="3rd radio button";
                  break;
        }
    });
```

My code above didn't work.  Can anyone one help me to show this problem?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incorrectly using jQuery selectors. Also you need to close the $(document).ready(). Right code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=content_type]').on('change', function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    switch(n)
    {
            case '1':
                  $('#show').html("1st radio button");
                  break;
            case '2':
                  $('#show').html("2nd radio button");
                  break;
            case '3':
                  $('#show').html("3rd radio button");
                  break;
        }
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmWxt/)

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
$('input[name=content_type]').on('change', function(){
```

OR

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
```

`#content_type` means you are selecting an element that has the id named content_type. and you don't have such any element.

After that your JS code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    switch(n)
    {
            case '1':
                  $('#show').html("1st radio button");
                  break;
            case '2':
                  $('#show').html("2nd radio button");
                  break;
            case '3':
                  $('#show').html("3rd radio button");
                  break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong.

1) **Instead of `#content_type`, you should use `input[name=content_type]`**

2) **Also, remove the `#` from getElementById:**

```
document.getElementById('#show')
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('show')
```

or change it to use jQuery:

```
$('#show').html("1st radio button");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified html ....i simply added a span to your messages

```
 <p><input type='radio' class="rad" name='content_type' value='1' />&nbsp;<span >This is content A of request</span></p>
<p><input type='radio' class="rad" name='content_type' value='2' />&nbsp;<span>This is content B of request</span></p>
<p><input type='radio'  name='content_type' value='3' />&nbsp;<span>This is content C of request</span></p>
<div id='show'></div>
```

And here is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').hide();
    $('input[name="content_type"]').on('change',function(){
       $('span').hide();
       $(this).next().show();
    });
});
```

And here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DCMct/)